# This site can't provide a secure connection ERR_SLL_PROTOCOL ERROR

Tags: django, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I have a google appengine project running in localhost.  Everything works fine until i go to the 'login' page.  When i go there i get the following error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

the appengine command i use to run the project is `dev_appserver.py" --host 127.0.0.1 .` This is run pycharm.  This only occurs in the 'login' endpoint and no other endpoint.

The console error i get is:

```
default: "GET /signin HTTP/1.1" 301 -
```

[image][image]

Comment: It looks like your page is redirecting you. However, you only show the `301` and not the entire response received. Use `curl -i YOUR_URL`. Look for the HTTP `Location` header. You did not post your code, so I cannot recommend a solution just the cause.

Comment: i added a screenshot of the full header

Comment: You are being redirected to `https://localhost:8080/signin`. Either your software is doing this or the authentication is doing this. More details on what you have configured.

Comment: this web app once deployed to google cloud does not return this error. I am only getting this error when i run it on localhost through pycharm.  What are the other details i can provide that will be useful?

Comment: Where have you configured the redirect URL? Show that code or configuration. The reason it works in App Engine is that SSL is supported.

Comment: please excuse the stupid questions but this is a project i took over and have limited familiarity with the back-end issues. When you ask where i have configured the redirect url, do you mean to say that when i GET request is sent, the response back attempts to redirect the user and that is why i am getting the SSL problems?  I will try to search for the redirect.  If you are fammliar with Python/Django, could you point to where i could begin my search? Thank you so much.

Comment: Post your code. I don't know what your code is doing, what type of authentication, etc. What are you using for account login?

Comment: One item that I just notice. You have `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` enabled. This forces SSL.

Answer (score 0):

to connect over HTTPS you need a valid SSL certificate on your server here is you local server as I understand from the message. you can get a certificate for your local server but I don't think it's worth the trouble while working locally. On the other hand when you deploy to Google App Engine, [you get SSL certificate automatically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) and it's managed by Google, that's why your code works without any problem in the deployment.